# Image in top right of other image?

Tags: html, css

I tried the following html:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
 <a href="https://example.com">
  <img src="image.png">
 </a>
 <a href="https://example2.com" style="top: 0px; right: 0px;">
  <img src="logo.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

What I was trying to accomplish was that the second link element, which contains an image, to be in the top right of the first image. However, the smaller image stays on the outside of the other one. Is there any possible way this could be done with the same layout? If not, then please tell me how I could make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of @TheMaleBeyonce is right. with your current layout, you should make sure this `div` element is just used to surround the outer image, and make sure the width of the `div` is equal to the outer image.

Suppose the width of outer image is 200px, the right code as below:

```html
<style>
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="wrap">
  <a href="https://example.com">
    <img src="image.png">
  </a>
  <a class="inner" href="https://example2.com">
    <img src="logo.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

[the demo](https://codepen.io/ricosmall/pen/QWbvXRv)

Answer (score 0):

So, what I would do is set the div to `position:relative;` and the 2nd image to `position:absolute; right:0; top:0;`. Assuming image 1 is as big as the div, this will make the second images position relative to the first image, so then you just position it where you like then set the width/height

Comment: I think they'd actually need to assign positions to the parent `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to give `position: relative` to the parent element, in this case: to the wrapper `div`. Then set `position: absolute` to your small image. Make sure you set `width: 100%` to your big image.

```css
.big-img {
  position: relative;
}

.small-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; position: relative; width: 500px;">
  <a class="big-img" href="https://example.com">
    <img width="100%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517148815978-75f6acaaf32c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  </a>
  <a class="small-img" href="https://example2.com" style="top: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515879218367-8466d910aaa4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.big-img { position: relative; }` is no need.

Comment: In this case its not needed, But its safe to use, if he wrap the `div` with another `div` then it may not work if he doesn't set `relative` position explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px
}
</style>

<div class="wrap">
  <a href="https://example.com">
    <img src="image.png" width="100%">
  </a>
  <a class="inner" href="https://example2.com">
    <img src="logo.png" width="100%">
  </a>
</div>
```